# Is there a way to abstract the import from a node module using typescript config files in the same style as the 'paths' property?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I am creating private node modules which for now might change considerably in structure which could mean splitting existing code into multiple packages.

If I have 100 files importing from a package that no longer holds the import I can do a find and replace but it becomes more difficult when classes are imported from that package...

so something like:

```
import { thing1, thing2} from 'my-package';
```

in the future may need to be:

```
import { thing1} from 'my-package';
import { thing2} from 'my-package2';
```

You can abstract imports using tsconfig like so:

```
"paths": {
  "@shared/*": ["app/shared/*"]
}
```

But I cant figure out a way to do the same thing with node modules so that if there is a bigger change I only need to change 1 line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create index.ts file , import and export your modules:

```
import { assign, assignWith } from 'lodash';
import { addDays } from 'date-fns';
export { assign, assignWith, addDays };
```

and import modules from that index:

```
import { assign, addDays } from './index';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/nrwl/nx
They can help you in using monorepo approach.
You can split your system into Applications and Libraries.